# How to Draw Pie chart based on time entries in google sheet

Tags: charts, google-sheets

Given the data arrangement in the image below (from google sheet) I tried to draw a chart showing time consumed by each activity, each activity has a start time, the end time of an activity is the start time of the next activity, I couldn't find a way to visualize such arrangement, is it possible ?

[image]

**Update: Solution**

This is what I reached now

[image]

Also I don't have to write end time, here is how I did it

[image]

End

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+1,COLUMN()-1))`

Duration

`=C:C-B:B`

Minutes

`= D:D * 24 * 60`

Note: To draw the chart I had to move the "Minutes" column to the right, i.e labels column has to be on the left for the chart to draw properly.

After that you can hide helping columns C and D as they are just created for intermediate steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may build a Pie chart based on time entries, but you need to convert time format into number format.

1. select column with time
2. go to menu `Format → Number → Number`

Or, for more visual, convert time formatted numbers into number of minutes:

`= Time * 24 * 60`

And then draw chart:

[image]